# Bash alias error

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, bashrc

I am fairly new to bashrc and am learning about the alias feature.

I am trying to create an alias that will open my java ide without me having to do 2 commands.

This is the commands I usually have to do

```
>cd idea-IU-143.381.42/bin
>./idea.sh
```

When I try to setup an alias

```
alias idea= 'cd ~/idea-IU-143.381.42/bin; ./idea.sh'
```

and restart my terminal I get the following error

```
bash: alias: cd ~/idea-IU-143.381.42/bin; ./idea.sh: not found
HP-Pavilion-TS-15-Notebook-PC:~$
```

Any help?

Comment: The second answer, the accepted one is wrong.

Comment: Change your alias to a function

Comment: I don't understand. Add the path to your PATH. There is no need for an alias.

Comment: @edwardtorvalds `cd`ing into a file? Very funny.

Answer (score 0):

Got it

I ended up making a function as suggested

```
idea(){
   cd ~/idea-IU-143.381.42/bin;
   ./idea.sh
}
```

Comment: This can work but you can also try this also , alias idea="~/idea-IU-143.381.42/bin/idea.sh" but before that just make sure idea.sh file should have executable permission. You can set executable permission by running this command chmod +x ~/idea-IU-143.381.42/bin/idea.sh from home directory.